# Sitecore xpath query not working

Tags: xpath, sitecore, sitecore6

Query 1: `/sitecore/content/FR/Cabinet/New Category/Attributes//*[@@TemplateID = '{95793C69-3E37-4CEB-9AF4-FD88276D85AA}']`

Query 2: `/sitecore/content/FR/Cabinet/New Category/Child Category 1/Attributes//*[@@TemplateID = '{95793C69-3E37-4CEB-9AF4-FD88276D85AA}']`

Query 1 works, with no problem - query 2 doesn't work, says `expected ::`. What's the difference, other than one is one more level deep. It also so happens that `/Child Category 1/` actually doesn't have any children in the `attributes` folder, while `/New Category/Attributes` does...

UPDATE - so it seems that "Child" is a keyword in Xpath...what is the workaround here?

Comment: if you could change "Child Category" by "Sub Category" you will avoid to fight vs xpath ;) otherwise try to escape "/\Child Category 1/"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can escape the category by wrapping it in hashes:

`/sitecore/content/FR/Cabinet/New Category/#Child Category 1#/ ...`

This also comes in handy when selecting items with fields that contain spaces:

`... //*[@#My Spaced Out Field# = '%Hey Yo!%']`

If you're building the query dynamically, you may want to consider escaping each token separately, using the `.Axes` API, or selecting the items using Lucene.

Comment: will having it as #/sitecore/content/FR/Cabinet/New Category/Child Category 1/# work?